# Why does Test::Spelling mark function/method names as having typos?

Tags: perl, spell-checking, perl-pod

Let's say I have this dummy Perl package in `test.pm`:

```
package test;

use strict;
use warnings;

=head1 DESCRIPTION

=head2 env

Return the environment name.

=cut

sub env { return "environment name"; }

=head2 hst

Return the history file name.

=cut

sub hst { return "history file"; }

=head2 hst_dir

Return the directory containing the history file.

=cut

sub hst_dir { return "history directory"; }

1;
```

Then, I run a spell check from command line using `Test::Spelling`...

```
$ perl -MTest::More -MTest::Spelling \
> -e 'pod_file_spelling_ok("test.pm", "spell check"); done_testing;'
```

..., and my function names `env` and `hst` are marked as a typos, but `hst_dir` is accepted:

```
not ok 1 - spell check
#   Failed test 'spell check'
#   at -e line 1.
# Errors:
#     env
#     hst
1..1
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
```

I know I can list a custom dictionary with `add_stopwords()`, but in my opinion function names should not be spell-checked at all.

Did I miss some fine-print in the documentation?

Comment: There are times where spell checking of function names and variable names would have been nice. Once upon a time I had to maintain code where "survey" was misspelled in two different ways in method names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're spell-cheking your POD, not your code.

`Test::Spelling` sees:

```
=head2 env
=head2 hst
```

How would it know that that are function names (not that it knows the concept of function names at all)?

It does see hst_dir as a perlish keyword, due to the underscore, whixh is not a normal character in a word. But that's as best it gets without stop words...

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I probably added `Pod::Coverage` into the mix in my mind, which makes the connection between `=headn`/`=item` lines and function names... My bad.